# How do I set the minimum label width in a Spark FormItem?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a way to set the minimum label width in a Spark FormItem? I have the following code and the checkbox is way to close to the label. I'd like to be able set a minimum label width.

```
<s:Form id="form1" width="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout id="formLayout1" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:FormItem label="Numbers" >
        <s:CheckBox id="numbersCheckbox" />
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Letters" >
        <s:CheckBox id="lettersCheckbox" />
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem >
        <s:Button id="myButton" 
                 label="My Label">
        </s:Button>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

I've come up with a partial solution but it has side effects. I use the following CSS and it moves the column over but it also affects any label with the id, "labelDisplay". Look at the button when using this CSS:

```
    spark|FormItemSkin #labelDisplay {
        paddingRight: 50;
        color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest or rather the best reusable approach would be to create your own `FormItemSkin` to modify the gap between the `FormItem`'s label and the content.

A quick solution could be the usage of separate layout objects for your form items:

```
<s:Form id="form1" width="100%" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout id="formLayout1"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:FormItem label="Numbers"  >
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:CheckBox id="numbersCheckbox" />
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Letters" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:CheckBox id="lettersCheckbox" left="20" />
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Comment: I'm modifying the skin now but it is cumbersome to keep having to create a new skin each time (different gaps). The solution above is helpful but I would have to add layout for each form item.